# NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription missing, but present

Tags: bluetooth, itunes-app

After successful upload I get:

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This is in the .plist:

> NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription 'MyApp' would
>   like to use Bluetooth

What is here wrong? In other App's it was working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that there were two .plist files in the project directory.
The used .plist file is defined here: "TARGETS", "Build settings", "Packaging", "INFOPLIST_FILE".

Answer (score 0):

find the info.plist file of your project and add the NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key the value it is string whatever you like. this feature is request on iOS 10.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHyPs.png)